# Can Uncrustify and/or Universal Indent GUI split string literals?

Tags: c++, uncrustify, universalindentgui

I'm using the Universal Indent GUI and Uncrustify for my C++ project. The code width is set to 80 characters and the code format is almost satisfying. This seems to work fine for regular code, but string literals are not split, and I would like that to happen as well.

The following example demonstrates I'm trying to achieve ...

Original:

```
Logger myLog;
myLog << "Long log message which exceeds line width." << std::endmsg;
```

Beautifed (align_left_shift=true):

```
Logger myLog;
myLog << 
"Long log message which exceeds line width." 
      << std::endmsg;
```

Preferred:

```
Logger myLog;
myLog << "Long log message which exceeds "
         "line width." 
      << std::endmsg;
// or
myLog << "Long log message which exceeds "
         "line width." << std::endmsg;
```

Is this possible with the auxiliary tools mentioned?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score -2):

```
myLog << "Long log message which exceeds " \
         "line width."
      << std::endmsg;
```

Comment: you've ruined my answer, for what I'm really grateful...

...you have to put \ at the end of the line with string constant (same way you do MACROs definition on multiple lines)

Comment: I think you did not understand my problem. Uncrustify is a code beautifer and I'm searching for a parameter which could achieve the above-mentioned format. Besides, your code change does not compile at all!

Comment: No, you don't have to put line-continuations between string constants. the compiler will happily merge them for you.

Comment: I've rolled the answer back to it's original version, with the exception that I "codified" it so that it renders as "source code" on the webpage. The breaking that occurred in the edit by @PhonicUK wasn't their fault; it was a bug in the Stack Overflow editor that inserted the `<br>`s. However, people should be more careful when editing other peoples' content. Stuff like this isn't typical around here. Apologies.